# form control is always pending in async validator

Tags: angular, jasmine, angular-reactive-forms

I have a form control that is as following:
....

```
direction: new Form("", [Validators.pattern("^[0-9]*$")],[requiredAsyncValidator])
```

and the requiredAsyncValidator is

```
export const requiredAsyncValidator = (control:FormControl):Promise<any> | Observable<any> => {
   return new Promise<any>((resolve,reject) => {
     setTimeout(() => {
        if(control.value == '' && control.touched) {
           resolve({required:true})
        }
        else{
          resolve(null)
        },100)
})
}
```

in my html I have attached `(blur)="direction.updateValueAndValidity()"` to the control 
however when I want to test it in my spec file I am getting PENDING state  on that control and thus my form is not valid 
this is my test:

```
component.direction.setValue(12)
component.direction.updateValueAndValidity()
fixture.detectChanges()
expect(component.form.valid).toBeTruthy() // false because direction field is PENDING
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap your test function into `fakeAsync` to have it executed in the [`fakeAsync`](https://angular.io/api/core/testing/fakeAsync) zone. Then use `flush` to simulates the asynchronous passage of time for the timers in the `fakeAsync` zone.

```
import { fakeAsync, flush } from '@angular/core/testing';
...

it('...', fakeAsync(() => {
    component.direction.setValue(12);
    component.direction.updateValueAndValidity();
    flush(); 
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(component.form.valid).toBeTruthy();   
}));
```

As an alternative you may use one of the Jasmine specific ways of testing asynchronous code (see https://jasmine.github.io/tutorials/async).